# bit_count function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hamming-distance

We are in the process of migrating a MySQL 5.7 database to PostgreSQL 9.6.

A real issue is the lack of `bit_count` function in PostgreSQL. This function is also not available in the upcoming version 10.

Current MySQL code snippet (simplified):

```
-- mysql specific, tested with 5.7.19
select code,phash,bit_count(phash ^ -9187530158960050433) as hd 
from documents 
where phash is not null and bit_count(phash ^ -9187530158960050433) < 7
order by hd;
```

We tried a naive solution (converting the BIGINT to a String and counting the "1"'s), but it performs terribly compared to MySQL.

Java [uses a trick from Hacker's Delight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7950608/868941), but AFAIK this is not possible with PostgreSQL, because the `>>>` operator is (also) not available.

**Question**: Is a there solution/workaround available *comparable with MySQL performance wise*?

**UPDATE 1**

Best solution i could find is based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459637/868941):

First create `bit_count` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bit_count(value bigint) 
RETURNS numeric 
AS $$ SELECT SUM((value >> bit) & 1) FROM generate_series(0, 63) bit $$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Now we can use almost the same SQL as with MySQL:

```
-- postgresql specific, tested with 9.6.5
select code,phash,bit_count(phash # -9187530158960050433) as hd 
from documents 
where phash is not null and bit_count(phash # -9187530158960050433) < 7
order by hd;
```

**UPDATE 2**

Based on @a_horse_with_no_name comment, i tried this function:

```
-- fastest implementation so far. 10 - 11 x faster than the naive solution (see UPDATE 1)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bit_count(value bigint) 
RETURNS integer 
AS $$ SELECT length(replace(value::bit(64)::text,'0','')); $$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

However, this is still 5 - 6 times slower than MySQL (tested wit exact the same data set of 200k phash values on the same hardware).

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Hi there. If you found a solution to your question you can add it as an answer and wait a bit before mark it as the accepted one. Just to make sure that no one has a better solution to offer.

Comment: I wonder if this is faster: `length(replace((phash # -9187530158960050433)::bit(64)::text,'0',''))`

Comment: If you are trying to compute the hamming distance of perceptual hashes or similar LSH bit strings, then this question may be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487949/302521 Check my answer there

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne This is indeed the background of this question. However, this question is specifically about finding the fastest way to emulate the MySQL bit_count function (which works perfectly well in a MySQL environment). Nevertheless, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Then this may be the cure: https://github.com/commonsmachinery/hmsearch/tree/postgres ... a postgres extension for hamming distance search ;)

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne Will check it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function bit_count is available since PostgreSQL version 14, see
[Bit String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html).

Example:

```
select bit_count(B'1101');
```

Result is 3.

Note that the function is defined for types bit and bit varying. So if you want to use it with integer values, you need to cast.

Example:

```
select cast (cast (1101 as text) as bit varying);
```

Result is B'1101'.

Combining both examples:

```
select bit_count(cast (cast (1101 as text) as bit varying));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Is a there solution/workaround available comparable with
>   MySQL performance wise?

To get a comparable speed, a compiled C function should be used.
If you can compile C code, see for instance
https://github.com/dverite/postgresql-functions/tree/master/hamming_weight

The code itself is very simple.

The result seems 10 times faster than the `bit_count` function based on counting the `0` characters in the `bit(64)` string as text.

Example:

plpgsql function:

```
test=> select sum(bit_count(x)) from generate_series(1,1000000) x;
   sum   
---------
 9884999
(1 row)

Time: 2442,340 ms
```

C function:

```
test=> select sum(hamming_weight(x::int8)) from generate_series(1,1000000) x;
   sum   
---------
 9884999
(1 row)

Time: 239,749 ms
```

Comment: Yes, this performs on par with MySQL. The downside of this solution is the "do it yourself" character.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compute the hamming distance of perceptual hashes or similar LSH bit strings, then this question may be a closely related to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/47487949/302521)

If you are looking specifically for a pre-built way to do hamming distance queries on a PostgreSQL database, then this may be the cure: an extension for [hamming distance search](http://github.com/commonsmachinery/hmsearch/tree/postgres)